How to get the first and last cell with values in a row for every row in a table in Excel?

So I wanted to solve a question, which was to compture YoY (Year over Year) growth rate for some specific conditions company, I was given this dataset above and I know the formula of YoY Growth rate. I used some formatting and Filtering in Excel to meet the conditions and this is the data im left with, above is the image.
So the formula for YoY growth rate is:
YoY Growth Rate = (Ending Year Value/Beginning Year Value) - 1
So I have the data for all different companies and all i need to do is find it. But the problem is, for every row, I want the Starting value and Ending value. I can enter it manually for all the rows and get the answer, but if there was much more data, I would have been screwed.
So is there an automated way that I can get the starting value and the ending value from column G to column U for every row?
Thanks in advance!
Didn't get the answer anywhere...

You tag both excel-2010 and -2007. Which version should it be?

For older Excel:
For first value in column:
=INDEX(A2:A112,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A2:A112)/(A2:A112^0),1))
For first value in row:
=INDEX(A2:U2,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(A2:U2)/(A2:U2^0),1))
For last value in column:
=INDEX(A2:A112,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW(A2:A112)/(A2:A112^0),1))
For last value in row:
=INDEX(A2:U2,AGGREGATE(14,6,COLUMN(A2:U2)/(A2:U2^0),1))
Office 365:
First value in column:
=@TOCOL(A2:A112,1)
First value in row:
=@TOROW(A2:U2,1)
Last value in column:
=TAKE(TOCOL(A2:A112,1),-1)
Last value in row:
=TAKE(TOCOL(A2:U2,1),,-1)
Your formula applied over several columns:
=BYCOL(A2:D112,LAMBDA(b,LET(v,TOCOL(b,1),TAKE(v,-1)/TAKE(v,1)-1)))
Your formula applied over several rows:
=BYROW(A2:U112,LAMBDA(b,LET(v,TOROW(b,1),TAKE(v,,-1)/TAKE(v,,1)-1)))

You already have answers for older versions of Excel.
For 365 you can use: =CHOOSECOLS(TOROW(G2:U2,1),1,-1) which will return a two column array of the first and last entries in that range.
To divide the last entry by the first entry and then subtract one:
= INDEX(SCAN(1,CHOOSECOLS(TOROW(G2:U2,1),1,-1),LAMBDA(a,b,b/a))-1,2)


Creative, using SCAN, I love it!

First and Last Numbers in Row
Legacy Excel (Single Cell (Copy Down))

First
=INDEX(G2:U2,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(G2:U2),0))


Last
=LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(G2:U2),G2:U2)


Result
=LOOKUP(2,1/ISNUMBER(G2:U2),G2:U2)/INDEX(G2:U2,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(G2:U2),0))-1



MS365 (Spills)

Result
=LET(data,G2:U11,
    xl,LAMBDA(d,fl,XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(d),d,,,fl)),
    BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r,xl(r,-1)/xl(r,1)-1)))



Example


I realise, seeing your answer, I answered for column-wise. Updated my answer. Your legacy solutions are more efficient, nice ones.
